# puppet agent doesn't retrieve files from master

Tags: puppet

I have a very basic question regarding to Puppet 3.0.1 configuration.

I setup a puppet master server (CentOS) with 2 agents (CentOS and Windows 7), all 3 can ping and access each other. There is no error at all.

I have copied a file under `/etc/puppet/files/test2.txt`

my `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp` contains these lines:

```
node default {
    file { "/tmp/testmaster.txt":
      owner => root,
      group => root,
      mode => 644,
      source => "puppet:///files/test2.txt"
    }
}
```

but there will no file be created on agent servers under `/tmp/` once I run `puppet agent --test`

here is the output:

```
[root@agent1 ~]# puppet agent --test
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for agent1.mydomain.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1354267916'
Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
```

`puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp` creates the `testmaster.txt` under `/tmp/` on master.

Comment: Not sure if it's of any help, but I suggest adding `ensure => present` in the `file` definition.

Comment: I'd also try running the master as `puppet master --no-daemonize --debug` and see what's going on there.

Comment: You don't have any classes defined? I'm not sure this works. What are the client side contents of `/var/lib/puppet/state/classes.txt /var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt` ? I would suggest just having one line like `node default { include myclass }` Use `puppet module generate myclass` to create the class directory structure. Then move the `file` section in the `init.pp` file which the generate command just created. Alternatively, you can have one line in the node section like above, but create the class _inside_ site.pp, like shown here: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, the problem was a missspelled filename, my site.pp was named (somehow) side.pp, renamed the file and everything works again.
this proofs that I sould not simply copy & paste stuffs from unauthorized tutorials.

Thank everybody to deal with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think you should try and run the following command on your client

> puppet agent --test --server=puppetmaster.domain.com

Comment: sorry, but none of both suggestions has worked. I'm really perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

Can your puppet clients connect to the puppet master via the puppet master's port (usually 8140)?

You could check this from the puppet client:

```
telnet puppetmaster 8140
```

Did your puppet master sign the certificate request from your puppet clients?

Check this from the puppet master:

```
puppetca -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the puppet file server in your configuration:

```
node default {
    file { "/tmp/testmaster.txt":
      owner => root,
      group => root,
      mode => 644,
      source => "puppet://puppetmaster.domain.com/files/test2.txt"
    }
}
```

Comment: shall I perhaps trigger a refresh and load of site.pp to inform agents ? (no idea how)

Comment: This is not correct, you can omit the puppet master name, but you must have the module path in the source URL.

Comment: Is this new? I did like that the last time I used puppet, 6 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the modules folder in your source path. This is a new requirement for puppet 3.0.

```
file{'/my-file':
  ensure => file,
  source => 'puppet:///modules/my_module/my-file',
}
```